# Question on algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers.

$$a=\sqrt{45-\sqrt{21-a}}$$

$$b=\sqrt{45+\sqrt{21-b}}$$

$$c=\sqrt{45-\sqrt{21+c}}$$

$$d=\sqrt{45+\sqrt{21+d}}$$

Find the value of **$$(abcd-2000)$$**

Comment: For one of the equations, square both sides and try to factorize the variable into a more cleaner form. Then repeat for other variables and see if you get an answer.

Comment: This is not [tag:linear-algebra]. Please read the tag description before applying a tag.

Comment: ok,sorry.I didn't know about the topic myself.

Comment: squaring is not helping.

Comment: Compute symbolically $abcd$, not evaluating the products like $45^2$. You should end up with an expression similar to those for $a,b,c,d$ for the product $abcd$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$a^2=45-\sqrt{21-a}\iff a^2-45=-\sqrt{21-a}$$

Squaring we get $$(a^2-45)^2=21-a\iff a^4-90a^2+a+45^2-21=0$$

Start with $b,c,d$ to find that  $a,b,-c,-d$ are the roots of $$t^4-90t^2+t+45^2-21=0$$

Now apply Vieta's formula to find $abcd$

Comment: Quite right, sorry, I didn't spot those minus signs. I think an extra few words would be helpful to clarify.

Comment: @Holographer, Edited the technical mistake

Comment: Completeness would require an argument that $a$, $b$, $-c$, $-d$ are actually distinct, but I don't think that's hard...

Comment: @Micah, I thought in that line. We can easily prove$$\frac{d(t^4-90t^2+t+45^2-21)}{dt}=4t^3-180t^2+90t $$ and $$t^4-90t^2+t+45^2-21$$ do not have any common factor